# Logback Custom DB Appender timeout

Tags: java, sql-server, osgi, logback

In my application there's a logback implementation, leveraging on this pretty straightforward xml configuration :

```
#logback-mw.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration debug="false">

    <appender name="DB"
        class="com.sample.osgi.core.MyDBAppender">
        <connectionSource
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
            </driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:sqlserver://mydbname:1401;databaseName=MWLOG;</url>
            <user>Andrea</user>
            <password>1234</password>
            <sqlDialect class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.dialect.MsSQLDialect" />
        </connectionSource>
        <insertHeaders>true</insertHeaders>
    </appender>


    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="DB" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

As you can see, I'm working with a MS sql server db instance (version 2017).

this is my code where I initialize the logger :

```
private void initMWLogger() {

        // Set up mwLogger using logback-mw.xml.
        try {
            JoranConfigurator jc = new JoranConfigurator();
            LoggerContext loggerCtx = new LoggerContext();
            jc.setContext(loggerCtx);
            loggerCtx.reset();

            InputStream configStream = MiddlewareConnectorService.class.getResourceAsStream(Constants.LOGGER_XML);

     //EXECUTION ON BELOW LINE IS HANGING FOR 10 MINUTES!!!!
jc.doConfigure(configStream); 

            mwLogger = loggerCtx.getLogger(MiddlewareConnectorService.class);
        } catch (JoranException e) {
            mwLogger = null;
        }
    }
```

In certain environment the given dns for the database connection is not reachable, so it happens that during startup my application hangs for 10 minutes.
Is it possible to configure a timeout on this ? I don't want my application to hang for this... in the worst scenario, I want that only db logging. is disabled. For the records I already tried with the *timeout query params mentioned on [this Ms sql server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2012).
Also, is someone able to suggest where this default timeouts of 10 minutes is coming from ? or how to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: However it is a hack, what you can do is the following: read the inputstream, parse it and get the hostname and try to [resolve](http://thushw.blogspot.com/2009/11/resolving-domain-names-quickly-with.html) it yourself with this custom code that applies timeout. If returns null, you can assume that DNS server is dead/slowed down, and you can give back a configured IP address of your database. You can change the original hostname to the "resolved" ip address in the parsed xml, and you can serialize it, and give as a bytearrayinputstream using String::getBytes() to JoranConfigurator.

Comment: Another option is extending JoranConfigurator, and do the same in a subclass, and this "magic" around the config inputstream is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @m4gic, I didn't check the suggested approach as I'm evaluating tinylog as logging library rather than logback. Leaving the question open as for now